# How can I install Pythons MySQLdb module on openSUSE?

Tags: python, mysql, opensuse

I currently have to install the Python package `MySQLdb` on a `openSUSE 11.3 "Teal"` that has `Python 2.6.5`.

Yes, I know that the current openSUSE is 13.1 and the last version that is supported is 11.4 (see [openSUSE version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE)). I also know that Python currently is in version 2.7.6 / 3.4.0. But I can't change that.

According to `pip` there is only a package [`mysqldbda`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqldbda) which seems not to help.

As `zypper search mysqldb` gave no results, I don't think there is a package like `python-mysqldb` in Debian based systems.

What should I do? How can I install the Python package MySQLdb on openSUSE?

If that is not possible: Are there alternative packages that I could use to execute simple queries (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE - no joins, no table creation, no deletes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try install it on OpenSUSE but python packages shouldn't be related to some specific distro of linux. If you want have and use different versions of python look for [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv). For mysql adapter you can look [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/). Command **pip install mysql-python** working well for python 2.6.6.

Comment: Yes, installing via pip is an option when not available otherwise. However, installing via system package management is to be preferred. This makes removing and updating packages and dependencies much easier. For MySQL-python you also need to add compilation dependencies, when installing via pip.